# Highcharts disabling marker not working

Tags: highcharts, markers, scatter

I am trying to disable markers on Highcharts but still see them when I hover over the data points and can't get it working. I have tried disabling the markers at chart, series and data levels and in each case, the markers just disappear and I can't get the data points when I hover over them. Here is the code where I'm disabling the markers for one data series:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    //Define the data points


    //Define and render the HighChart
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: "container",
            defaultSeriesType: "scatter"
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                lineWidth: 2
            }
        },
       series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
     marker: {
   enabled: false
     }
  }, 
{data: [129.9, 171.5, 10.4, 12.2, 14.0, 17.0, 13.6, 14.5, 21.4, 19.1, 9.6, 5.4]}]


    })

})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="height: 600px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: It looks like what you really want is a line chart. Why not use a line type instead of a scatter type? Scatter plots exist for the purpose of displaying a marker at a specific point. Therefore, disabling the marker is going to be problematic.

Answer (score 3):

For a scatter chart, the hover event happens on the marker.  If you disable the markers, you disable the hover event.  I'd just set the [fillColor](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker.fillColor) to `transparent`:

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    marker: {
       fillColor: 'transparent'
    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f0qvaymz/).

**EDITS**

I was wrong, you can disable the marker and still get mouseovers to work.  It doesn't work in your case, though, because you are using a scatter chart.  Switching to a default line series and [all is well.](http://jsfiddle.net/f0qvaymz/1/)

Comment: Many thanks for this. I have tried this and it works. I still don't quite understand why the other approach doesn't work though because it works on the Highcharts website - see: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-enabled-false/

Comment: @Thomas, it's because you are using a scatter chart, see edits above.